# Qual a melhor forma de manter estado entre rotas com Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tenho uma tela de busca onde possuo alguns filtros, depois realizado os filtros, posso clicar nos registros e ir para uma tela de "detalhes" e depois posso editar ou voltar para a tela de pesquisa.

Qual a melhor forma de manter estado entre a navegação estre estas paginas?

Sei que é possivel fazer com um serviço "singleton", também posso utilizar o localStorage ou ainda o sessionStorage.

Qual seria a forma mais elegante? O Angular tem alguma solução no "pacote"?

Comment: vc tem que usar o localStorage mesmo, Se quiser fazer de uma maneira mais elegante você pode ter um gerenciador de estado como ngrx.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada nesse ngrx, ainda não estou gostando de usar o localStorage =(... mas por enquanto optei por criar um service singleton